# A good multithread downloads manager for Linux?

Tags: linux, download, download-manager

Does someone knows a good multithread downloads manager for linux? I am using Lucid Lynx, I use to use multiget but it hasn't been updated since 2007.

I'd like it to support login for sites like rapidshare, something like FlashGet in win.

By multithread I dont only mean multiple downloads but like FlashGet "Jets" feature to download files faster.

Answer (score 5):

[jDownloader](http://www.jdownloader.org/) does the thing.

Answer (score 4):

For segmented download use [axel](http://axel.alioth.debian.org/). Of course it will not work for rapidshare-like services (sessions per IP).

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried the Firefox plugin DownThemAll?
Also, Opera has similar functionality built-in, with very powerful URL grepping from the Links page.

Comment: is this multithread?

Answer (score 2):

[Aria2c](http://aria2.sourceforge.net) is pretty good. Just installed on Fedora 16 and downloading files with no issues.

Answer (score 0):

WebDownloade for X seems to do the work.

edit: it doesnt work for rapidshare :(

Answer (score 0):

A general tool is `aria2`, but it will not support things like rapidshare, only normal downloads. For sites with hoops for you to jump through, you will need a specialized tool. Also, segmented downloads may not work anyway because they typically restrict you to one active download session per ip address -- you'd need a farm of machines to bypass that.

Answer (score 0):

JDownloader from jdownloader.org
It's indicated for sites like rapidshare.com, especially if you have a premium account (you will be automatically be logged in and download at full speed)

Answer (score 0):

xdman from sourceforge ---- best multisegment downloader with firefox integration